# Table Editing React without Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I want to display some data inside a table, data that I fetch from a DB. I've made the fetch function and it works, but now I have a question about how I should perform some operations.

1) Let's say I add a column for each row in which I insert an "X" button: if I click it the related row will be removed from both the table and the DB.

2) Let's say I can add a row from the same page: if I do that, this new row must be added in both table and DB.

Now, in both cases I can simply perform a query on the DB, then render again the page which will query again the SELECT query on the DB, but I think it's not a good solution since I can avoid the SELECT query: I can just execute the REMOVE or ADD query to remove/add the new record, and then edit the variable this.state.customer withtout executing the query again.

The problem is: if I modify this.state.customer, then the page is rendered again, therefore the query is performed again.. This is the render() function

```
render() {
    let contents = this.state.loading
        ? <p><em>Loading Data From DB...</em></p>
        : Customer.render_Customers(this.state.customers);

    return (
        <div className="first-container">
            <h1>Customer</h1>
            {contents}                
        </div>
    );
```

where in render_Costumer I just return a table in which each row is a record inside a JSON, and the loading variable became true when the first SELECT query has finished and I have the data I want to display.

Is there a way I can edit the table without performing the SELECT query again? I think it could be better: if the table should contains 10000 records, I would avoid a lot of data transmission, I guess.

So far I thought about using Jquery and manipulating the DOM, but I'm trying to not use Jquery and focusing only on React so that I can learn it.

Comment: When is your query called ? You should be able to put it in a function whom would not be called on render.

Comment: Damn, you are right, I have the query in the constructor, so it is called once, not every time the page is rendered.
There is still one "problem": let's say I edit the array (deleting one record) containing the records I'm showing, the page will page rendered again with all the records expect the one I deleted. But! If I have like 10k records, this means that it will render again (10k-1) records, while I think it could be better/faster to just edit the DOM and deleting the record by myself.. Is this wrong in React?